# PG_Search rendering more data than I want to in results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-search

I'm using pg_search to do some basic search in my Rails app, but when I try and render certain things like the name attribute of each result, it also renders a pg_search hash of all the data for that result. Here's my search results page code:

```
<ul class="results">
    <%= @pg_search_documents.each do |pg_search_document| %>
    <%= pg_search_document.searchable.name %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

How can I *just* render the name attribute of the result, and not all the other data for that pg_search document?

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
<ul class="results">
    <% @pg_search_documents.each do |pg_search_document| %>
    <%= pg_search_document.searchable.name %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

`<%=  %>` is for output-ing

`<% %>` is evaluating . Since just  you want to evaluate, use this